# Crop image intent, return values

Tags: android, android-intent, crop

I've found this code for start crop intent inside my android app:

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFile.getPath());
 Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
 cropIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(mFile), "image/*");
 cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
 cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
 cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
 cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
 cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
 cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
 startActivityForResult(cropIntent, 2);
```

Now i would put inside intent this information:

- picture output name and path
- picture output format (jpeg)
- picture output quality

How can i do?

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html), let alone one that necessarily does what you seek. Use a third-party library for the cropping, and either use a third-party library or your own code for the additional capabilities.

Comment: I'll use this intent on device where this kink of intent works well. I've try also some libraries on that link, but they don't satisfy me (bad image quality, etc)